# How do you filter a rest api call?

Tags: azure, powershell, rest

Using the Usage Details Rest API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list

In PowerShell, I have a call that looks like this:

```
Param=@{
  Method = 'Get'
  Uri = $MyUri
Headers = @{
  Authorization = "Bearer" + $Token
}

Request = Invoke-RestMethod @Param
```

My question is, with the API in the URL above, how do I filter in information for the date into the above code?

Comment: Did you try out the url examples shown in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range

Comment: You just need to set (example from the link):`?$filter=properties%2FusageStart%20ge%20'2020-02-01'%20and%20properties%2FusageEnd%20le%20'2020-02-29'` in your `$MyUri`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) & [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale) Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

Based on this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range);

"You just need to set (For example):`?$filter=properties%2FusageStart%20ge%20'2020-02-01'%20and%20properties%2FusageEnd%20le%20'2020-02-29'` in your `$MyUri` ."